# GGTS: gsp editor is not working

Tags: eclipse, ggts

I'm using 3.6.4 version of GGTS. The gsp editor is not working which worked fine previously. 
When I first click to open the gsp file, I will get an error "Editor could not be initialized". The details are below.

```
java.lang.LinkageError: org/codehaus/groovy/ast/ModuleNode
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.groovy.elements.AbstractGrailsElement.getGroovyClass(AbstractGrailsElement.java:70)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.groovy.elements.TagLibClass.getNamespace(TagLibClass.java:290)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.gsp.tags.PerProjectTagProvider.initializeTaglibs(PerProjectTagProvider.java:360)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.gsp.tags.PerProjectTagProvider.initializeAllTags(PerProjectTagProvider.java:232)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.gsp.tags.PerProjectTagProvider.ensureInitialized(PerProjectTagProvider.java:206)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.gsp.tags.PerProjectTagProvider.getCorrespondingCMDocument(PerProjectTagProvider.java:473)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.gsp.tags.GSPModelQueryCMProvider.getCorrespondingCMDocument(GSPModelQueryCMProvider.java:74)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.contentmodel.modelqueryimpl.SimpleAssociationProvider.getCorrespondingCMDocument(SimpleAssociationProvider.java:36)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.contentmodel.modelqueryimpl.SimpleAssociationProvider.getCMElementDeclaration(SimpleAssociationProvider.java:42)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.contentmodel.modelqueryimpl.ModelQueryImpl.getCMElementDeclaration(ModelQueryImpl.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.internal.modelquery.JSPModelQueryImpl.getCMElementDeclaration(JSPModelQueryImpl.java:49)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.ElementImpl.getDeclaration(ElementImpl.java:360)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.ElementImpl.isContainer(ElementImpl.java:845)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelParser.insertStartTag(XMLModelParser.java:1405)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelParser.insertStartTag(XMLModelParser.java:1499)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelParser.insertStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelParser.java:1510)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelParser.replaceStructuredDocumentRegions(XMLModelParser.java:2354)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.DOMModelImpl.internalSetNewDocument(DOMModelImpl.java:661)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.DOMModelImpl.setStructuredDocument(DOMModelImpl.java:936)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.gsp.model.GSPStructuredModel.setStructuredDocument(GSPStructuredModel.java:97)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.AbstractModelLoader.createModel(AbstractModelLoader.java:127)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.FileBufferModelManager.getModel(FileBufferModelManager.java:852)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl._getModelFor(ModelManagerImpl.java:639)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl.getModelForEdit(ModelManagerImpl.java:1380)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.tryToGetModel(StructuredTextEditor.java:2004)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.doSetInput(StructuredTextEditor.java:1944)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3220)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:466)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:374)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$13.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2157)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2153)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3238)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3265)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.init(StructuredTextEditor.java:2620)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:390)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:305)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:888)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:869)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:120)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:258)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:127)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:983)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1246)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:69)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4734)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:218)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:488)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:454)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:705)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:392)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1145)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3210)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$23(WorkbenchPage.java:3125)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$9.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3107)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3102)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3066)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3056)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:541)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:500)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:360)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:268)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.OpenAndExpand.run(OpenAndExpand.java:50)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:229)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$3.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:185)
at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:853)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:178)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:850)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1142)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:462)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1249)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:278)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:272)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:313)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Then, I close the tag and click to open the same gsp file again, the file will be opened but it's in pure text format. All the gsp assist feature is gone.
Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is just re-install the GGTS. Then everything works.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go into preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations
2. Under File types, find *.gsp.
3. Under Associated editors, remove GSP Editor (default)
4. Press Add, and add GSP Editor again, and make it default.

This worked for me.